# I'm trying to format a number in apps script that will return the users negative input with -£3.50 instead of £-3.50

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, currency-formatting

I'm trying to format a number in apps script that will return the users negative input  with -£3.50" instead of  £-3.50, however, my code doesn't seem to work, I'm using a google spreadsheet for this, can anyone help me with this?

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var snacks = ui.prompt('Numbers only.', 'Please enter the price of the snacks.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var snacksPrice = snacks.getResponseText();
  if (snacksPrice = "-") {
    snacksPrice = snacksPrice.toFixed(2);
    snacksP = snacksPrice.split("");
    ui.alert(snacksP[0] + "£" + snacksP[1] + snacksP[2] + snacksP[3]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the javascript `Intl.NumberFormat` method for formatting numbers. The `Intl.NumberFormat` object enables language-sensitive number formatting.

now, I've refactored your code so that you can understand what has changed.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

// here I'm basically creating a new `numberFormat` instance.
// your currency is pounds `£`, therefore you need to put currecy value as *GBP* 

const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' })

var snacks = ui.prompt('Numbers only.', 'Please enter the price of the snacks.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);

// use parseFloat to convert string to number. e.g. '-11.2' -> -11.2

var snacksPrice = parseFloat(snacks.getResponseText());

ui.alert(nf.format(snacksPrice));
```

Here is a basic example:

```js
const yourNumber = -100
const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' })
console.log(nf.format(yourNumber))
```

if you need to know more about it, please check out mdn documantation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: yeah, I'm still editing the post. thank you!